# How to use flush() for PrintWriter

Tags: java, java-io

I have some codes like this:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedReader(....));
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    pw.println("a");
    pw.flush();// flush each time when println()?
}
pw.close();
```

Is the **flush()** in each 'for' statement necessarily? I heard that flush() would auto invoke  when invoke **close()** .
If I write code like this:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedReader(....), true);
```

and I wouldn't write **pw.flush()** anymore? Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to flush inside loops like this You are losing the benefit of any buffering.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`flush()` is *probably* not required in your example.

What it does is ensure that anything written to the writer prior to the call to `flush()` is written to the underlying stream, rather than sit in some internal buffer.

The method comes in handy in several types of circumstances:

1. If another process (or thread) needs to examine the file while it's being written to, and it's important that the other process sees all the recent writes.
2. If the writing process might crash, and it's important that no writes to the file get lost.
3. If you're writing to the console, and need to make sure that every message is shown as soon as it's written.

Comment: Another question title that has very little to do with the question, yet has nearly 5K views

Answer (score 0):

The second option is better to use, as it will create an autoflushable PrintWriter object. And if you use first case, then I don't think **flush()** is required in your example case.

Answer (score 0):

**Close method flushes before closing.** If you use **close()**, **flush()** is not necessary in your first and second example (except u wanna use flush before closing).

On top of that your second example also flushes automatically when using the methods: println, printf, or format

Comment: This question is fairly old and already has an accepted answer. How does your answer improve the previous accepted answer?