# Printing an integer using printwriter vs System.out.print

Tags: java, arrays, printwriter

I'm trying to read the bytes I have in an array to the console and if I use a PrintWriter object, nothing is printed to the screen, however, using System.out.println() works fine.  Why?

Here is what my code looks like:

```
private static void readByteArray(byte[] bytes) {
   ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);

   int c;
   while((c = bais.read()) != -1) {
   pw.print(c);
}
```

That code doesn't work, but if I do this:

```
private static void readByteArray(byte[] bytes) {
   ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);

   int c;
   while((c = bais.read()) != -1) {
   System.out.println(c);
}
```

It prints.

What is the difference?  According to this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html the PrintWriter method `print(int i)` prints an integer so I'm confused.

Comment: did you try using `pw.println` instead of `print` in your first function?

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927281/how-to-use-flush-for-printwriter

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I just tried that and nothing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I added a flush after each read and it works!  can you explain why this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `System.out` variable is referencing an object of type `PrintStream` which wraps a `BufferedOutputStream` (at least in Oracle JDK 7). When you call one of the `printX()` or `write()` methods on `PrintStream`, it internally flushes the buffer of the underlying `BufferedOutputStream`.

That doesn't happen with `PrintWriter`. You have to do it yourself. Alternatively, you can create a `PrintWriter` with an `autoFlush` property set to `true` which will flush on each write.

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
```

If you read this [constructor's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29), it states

> - **autoFlush** A boolean; if true, the println, printf, or format methods
>     will flush the output buffer