# Java write to file

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static String title;
    public static String text;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://support.cygnos.xyz/zast.html").get();
        Elements kolumny = doc.select("tr");
        title = doc.title();
        System.out.println("===== " + title + "=====\n");
        for (Element szczegolowe : kolumny) { 
            System.out.println(szczegolowe.text());
            text = szczegolowe.text();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("last.txt"));
            out.println(szczegolowe.text());
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Why this is generating into file only one line, not full data from table which i parse?

Output from console:

http://support.cygnos.xyz/output.txt

File:

> 7 3 TIE(3) - 20ZS L. Rakojc

Comment: What do you think `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("last.txt"));` does? Are you sure its place is inside loop? Same question about `out.close();`

Answer (score 0):

Create your writer outside the loop, or you will override the file each time.

Also, close the writer after the loop, once you're done writing to the file.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("last.txt"));

for (Element szczegolowe : kolumny) { 
        System.out.println(szczegolowe.text());
        text = szczegolowe.text();

        out.println(szczegolowe.text());
        out.flush();

}

out.close();
```

Comment: You can actually flush after each line, but you're right that we could also flush once before closing, instead.

Comment: @Berger "we could also flush once before closing" wouldn't `close` method flush automatically? Do we really need explicit `flush` call right before `close`?

Comment: @Pshemo :  the javadoc of the PrintWriter's constructor  which is used in this example, says : "Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing."  .  However, there is a discussion here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927281/how-to-use-flush-for-printwriter

Comment: @Berger I am not asking about flushing after each line, but after before `close` method. Flushing manually after each line is OK if that is what we *want*. But flushing right before `close()` is from what I remember redundant.

Comment: @Pshemo : yes it is probably redundant, I can't remember of any problem when not using flush() .

Answer (score 0):

Because you do open the file and close it in the for loop, making it erase its content and write only the last row. To make it work open the file and close it only once (outside the loop):

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("last.txt"));
for (Element szczegolowe : kolumny) { 
        System.out.println(szczegolowe.text());
        text = szczegolowe.text();
        out.println(szczegolowe.text());
}
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing a new `PrintWriter` for each iteration in your loop, causing the file to be truncated again and again.

Maybe to solution would be to initialize the `PrintWriter` before the loop and write to in within the loop and close it afterwards.