# Java print writer wraps around

Tags: java, scala, sed, printwriter, bufferedwriter

I am using a Java PrintWriter to write a Scala HashMap to file. This is the code I am using:

```
def writeToFileAsMapUsingPrintWriter(data: mutable.HashMap[String, Int], outputFilename: String, outputDirectoryPath: String): Unit = {
val myfile = new File (outputDirectoryPath, outputFilename);
val printWriter = new PrintWriter(myfile);
for ((k, v) <- data) {
  printWriter.println(s"$k->$v")
}
printWriter.close ();}
```

Now the problem is this PrintWriter wraps some lines around to the next newline in the output file. 
Eg:

`CC PRP VBP JJ1 to get JJ2 IN
->821065
2000 DT RBS JJ1 IN the hundred of JJ2 year->10521306
PRP be JJ1 TO VB JJ2 IN
->10521307
DT world POS JJ1 marketer , MD lead JJ2 effort->10521308`

This becomes a problem because when I read this file back, I go line by line, and I encounter lines without an id, as above. And the interesting part is it occurs only for the same lines always. There are longer lines than that, but they don't wrap around.

I tried running the PrintWriter separately for just with these 5 lines in a HashMap, then it prints these lines in the same line i.e without wrapping around. Its only when I feed it my 11GB hash map that this occurs. I also tried replacing the println with a print, but didn't make a difference.

`printWriter.print(s"$k->$v\n")`

I can maybe go in with an sed command and fix these lines in the file, but that will fix only these 2, and wont fix others. Plus it is just a temporary fix.

Sounds like some kind of memory issue to me. Has anyone encountered this before?

Meanwhile, I will try out more trial and error methods. So next I am going to replace the PrintWriter with a BufferedWriter, using the flush() command as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927281/how-to-use-flush-for-printwriter?rq=1) etc.

Just that it takes 12 hours to run my program once, so the turn around time is huge. Hence asking just in case if anyone has encountered this before.

Answer (score 0):

How sure are you that your keys don't actually contain newlines? That can sometimes be hard to spot. My guess is this might resolve it:

```
printWriter.println(s"${k.trim()}->$v")
```

I am very skeptical that there is any sort of memory issue or other bug with the JVM or Java standard library.