# Getting input from TextArea and appending the input to existing .txt file

Tags: java, file-io, text-files, fxml, filewriter

I have created a java fxml and a corresponding controller class.

In my controller class I have:

```
@FXML
private TextArea addBox;
@FXML
private Button addButton;
```

I also have a 'add' button with a attached method called addButton, so when 'add' button is pressed input from TextArea is added to my existing Data.txt file I have tried:

```
 private void addButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
   Writer output;
   output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Data.txt", true));
   output.append(addBox.getText());
   output.close();
}
```

and

```
    @FXML
private void addButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
   try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Data.txt", true);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
 {
out.println(addBox.getText());


} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

Similarly,if I put John into TextArea(addBox) and click 'delete' button it should delete a row(s) that has the word John in it. I can't get these two methods to work. Is there something wrong with AddBox.getText();? shouldn't it get the input and treat it like String?

```
@FXML
private void deleteButton(ActionEvent event) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File inputFile = new File("Data.txt");
    File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    String lineToRemove = addBox.getText();
    String currentLine;

    while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        if (trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) {
            continue;
        }
        writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
    boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
}
```

It seems to me that there aren't any syntax errors as it runs without errors. However, it won't add anything to existing .txt file.

Comment: For one, don't do this: `catch (IOException e) {}` At least print out the stacktrace of any exceptions that might crop up: `catch (IOException e) { e.printStacktrace(); }`

Comment: `"It seems to me that there aren't any syntax errors as it runs without errors. However, it won't add anything to existing .txt file."` -- and again without proper handling of exceptions, you really can't say this. Your code could be throwing exceptions, but you're swallowing them and not handling them.

Comment: That's a good point! I will fix it and see if it gives me an error

Comment: Hi Hovercraft, I replaced my code catch (IOException e) {} with your code catch (IOException e) { e.printStacktrace(); } , but  I get this error message:
'cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method printStacktrace()
  location: variable e of type IOException'

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to put my code nicely like yours in comment section

Comment: Sorry, capitalized wrong: It should be `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Read [comment formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: No worries, I used `catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` and the program still runs without an error. What does that mean? What should I fix? Sorry if this is stupid question, It's been a month since I started studying java, but I can't go to sleep w/o figuring out. I have been stuck for a day now...

Answer (score 0):

Is your printwriter used for multiple instances? You might want to try using pw.flush() after every write - it can do some weird things otherwise. More here.

[How to use flush() for PrintWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927281/how-to-use-flush-for-printwriter)

Additionally, do you know if the addbox.getText() is yielding any text to pass to the printwriter? You could always add an intermediate variable and check if it has anything for quick and easy troubleshooting.

Also, I'd add this in comments, but I can't yet - you might wanna try catching Exception e instead of just IOException, if you're looking for every possible exception that can happen.